# Azure - Uploaded MVC Project returns 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Using Visual Studio 2019 I tried to Publish the MVC Project I've been working on. It goes well, but the default route returns a 404 Not Found. Other routes for login/register load the correct html content. This all works well on my localhost. I've been searching around but can only find things relating to Angular etc.

The index page loads content from a database, which I haven't set-up yet if that causes any issues?

Any help is appreciated as I'm boggled.

Comment: Have you got application insights enabled to check if any exceptions are occurring? Would you be able to post details of your Startup.cs?

Comment: @DavidC I feel the application not being connected to a database with the migrations applied is causing the issue. I just need to figure out how Azure works with migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. For anyone wondering in the future, if the page reads content from a database make sure the Migrations are applied and the database is exactly how it is on your local machine (This was my issue anyway).

Comment: Sounds like a sensible pre-requisite to have your dependencies deployed too! :)